# Adding the elements from the coredata in to a dictionary and then to an nsmutablearray?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

i have an application in which i am trying to create an nsmutablearray of dictionaries.all are working fine but the problem is only the last element is adding in count times of the coredata array.here is how i am doing it `

```
 rateValues=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    rateValues1=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    if(messagesArray!=nil)
    {
        for (Messagestable *rating in messagesArray)
        {
                        //[rateValues  addObject:rating.message];

             [rateValues1 setObject:rating.fromid forKey:@"fromid"];
               [rateValues1 setObject:rating.toid forKey:@"toid"];
             [rateValues1 setObject:rating.sendingtime forKey:@"sendingtime"];
            [rateValues1 setObject:rating.message forKey:@"message"];
            [rateValues1 setObject:rating.fromname forKey:@"fromname"];

            [rateValues  addObject:rateValues1];

        }



    }
    else{
        //NSLog(@"array empty");
        return;
    }

    NSLog(@"%@",rateValues);
```

`my array is contaning only the last element 4 times.ie it is the count of the data in coredata.Can anybody help me?

Comment: You will have to allocate `rateValues1` in loop body .... !!

Comment: thanks for the attention my dearfriend..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a new dictionary each iteration; what you are currently doing is overwriting your single dictionary and re-adding it to the array.

```
rateValues=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
if(messagesArray!=nil)
{
    for (Messagestable *rating in messagesArray)
    {
        NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
        [rateValues1 setObject:rating.fromid forKey:@"fromid"];
        [rateValues1 setObject:rating.toid forKey:@"toid"];
        [rateValues1 setObject:rating.sendingtime forKey:@"sendingtime"];
        [rateValues1 setObject:rating.message forKey:@"message"];
        [rateValues1 setObject:rating.fromname forKey:@"fromname"];

        [rateValues  addObject:dict];
    }
}
else{
    //NSLog(@"array empty");
    return;
}

NSLog(@"%@",rateValues);
```

Comment: Of course `rateValues1` should be `dict` now when setting the objects, but this is the correct answer.